# Get all records that exist in both the tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

Below are two tables with some sample data :-

```
Uploads:  
id: 1 , file_ref:abc  
id: 2, file_ref: abc1  
id: 4, file_ref: abc3  
id: 5, file_ref: abc4  
id: 6, file_ref: abc5  
id: 7, file_ref: abc6  

media:  
id: 3, name: 'My Doc' , type: doc  
id: 6, name: 'My Img' , type: img
```

I have these 2 models in rails.
Now in my controller I want to get all records in uploads if their id exists in the media table i.e. records from upload table with ids 3 and 6.

Comment: The id is shared? So the only record to return is the `id: 6, file_ref: abc5  
`, because the `id 3` does not exists in the table media?

Comment: can you change the value of ** abc5** to be **5** or do you have to first get the number out and then find

Comment: All media would exist in the uploads, but the file_ref is only available in the uploads which is what I want. So I have to get both records with id 6 and 3 from the uploads table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) where joining condition must be the ids of the table

```
Upload.joins("INNER JOIN medias ON media.id = uploads.id")
```

This will be translated to:

```
"SELECT `uploads`.* FROM `uploads` INNER JOIN media ON media.id = uploads.id"
```

Edit:

As [MrYoshiji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976775/mryoshiji) said in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549944/get-all-records-that-exist-in-both-the-tables/45550094#comment78059871_45550054), `Upload.where(id: Media.all)` also will do a single query.

So both options option will return all the upload records which ids exists in the media table

Answer (score 1):

You can do a subquery in your call

I think that it should look something like this

`Upload.where(media_id: Media.all.map(&:id))`

I hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a relationship between them? From the sounds of it you haven't (you really should), but if you haven't then try:

```
ids = Media.all.ids
Upload.where(id: ids)
```

or as one line

```
Upload.where(id: Media.all.ids)
```

This will return all records in your upload table that has an ID that exists in the media table.

Comment: Mark, the disadvantage of doing this, is that you are doing two queries to the database, one for the `Media.all.ids` and one for the `Upload.where`. With the INNER JOIN you are doing only one.

Comment: `Upload.where(id: Media.all)` will do a single SQL query with a nested `SELECT medias.id [...] FROM medias` -- but that is weird to assume that Media <-> Upload relation is only defined by the equality of their `id`

Comment: As @MrYoshiji mentions, withouth the `ids`, it will do a single query